# assigning values to a bitset from multiple int types

Tags: c++, c++11, bitset

I am using a bitset that is created in the following way

```
std::bitset<4> bitset;
```

I wanted to know how I can assign a value to a bitset if I have ints with the 
values `A=0,B=1,C=1,D=0` ?

I have read that I could do this

```
bitset.set(0, false);
bitset.set(1, true);
bitset.set(2, true);
bitset.set(3, false);
```

I wanted to know if there was a faster way for this ? Preferably a single statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By example

```
std::bitset<4> bitset(6UL);
```

> I wanted to know how I can assign a value to a bitset if I have ints with the values A=0,B=1,C=1,D=0 ?

If you have multiple variable (one variable for every bit) I suppose the best you can do is assign every single bit, how do you know

```
bitset.set(0, (A != 0));
bitset.set(1, (B != 0));
bitset.set(2, (C != 0));
bitset.set(3, (D != 0));
```

or, simpler,

```
bitset.set(0, A);
bitset.set(1, B);
bitset.set(2, C);
bitset.set(3, D);
```

If you really want initialize with a single statement (and if the variable have only `0` and `1` values), I suppose you can use the bitshift

```
std::bitset<4> bitset((A << 3)|(B << 2)|(C << 1)|D);
```

Comment: Is there anyway of doing this with variables ? I just updated my question. I know i can concatenate the integers after converting them to a string

Comment: @JamesFranco - answer modified (hope this helps)